# What is the order of ResultSet returned by PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys() when batching

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to map the returned primary key as a foreign key in a subtable class. This is an example of what I'm working on.

**Note: all code is used to explain the problem and may not compile. This is also using postgresql and is not required to be portable to other databases. The driver library is `org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1209`**

This is an example main class Record and subtable class RecordInfo.

```
class Record {
    String id; //primary key
    String data;
    List<RecordInfo> list; 
}
```

RecordInfo has a primary key and foreign key.

```
class RecordInfo {
    String recordId; //foreign key for Record
    String id; //primary key
    String data;
}
```

When inserting individual rows for Record getGeneratedKeys() will return a ResultSet with one row containing the keys.

```
String insertSql = "INSERT INTO record (data) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement insertPs = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql, new String[]{"id"});
...map object into insertPs...
insertPs.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rsKey = insertPs.getGeneratedKeys();
if(rsKey.next()) {
    record.id = rsKey.getString("id");
}
```

This makes it easy to map the Record id back into the original object and use it as the foreign key in each RecordInfo. If I switch the algorithm to batch the Record inserts is the returned ResultSet in the same order as the original list of Record objects?

```
PreparedStatement insertPs = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql, new String[]{"id"});
for(Record record : records) {
    ...map object into insertPs...
    insertPs.addBatch();
}
insertPs.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = insertPs.getGeneratedKeys();
for(Record record : records) {
    rs.next();
    record.id = rs.getString("id");
}
```

I'm worried that I will be assigning foreign keys to the wrong RecordInfo objects if the order in rs is not the same as my record list. Is there a better way to map returned keys? Should I consider not batching my inserts?

Comment: Good question. Based on the source code for the `postgresql-jdbc-42.2-5` driver, it *seems like* they are coming back in the same order. With the source jar attached, run your debugger and step through the driver code to watch how it handles the `generatedKeys`. However, I don't see anything in the documentation about a defined order so be *very* careful about depending on implementation specific behavior, you should generally avoid it.